# Error when moving mouse over map. No map events set

Tags: google-maps-api-3, mouseevent

I am getting an error when moving the mouse over the map. It appears as though a mouseover/mousemove event is being fired although I haven't set any for the map. This is throwing an error in a block of code the debug window calls "eval code (8)"

The error is on "h=new O(s.lat(),s.lng())" in this function...

function SF(a,b,c,d){var e=new az(d);ep;bp;var f=c.Eb;M([Af,qs,cs,hr,gr,os,ps,ns],function(d){P[y](b,d,function(h,n,r){var s=aSn;h=new O(s.lat(),s.lng());s=c.get("projection")db;n=new Rr(h,r,n,s);var u;r=Ns(Is);h=f.Od;var x=n.Xa&&ir(n.Xa);if(f.b)s=f.b,u=f.d;else if(d==gr||x)u=s=null;else{for(var C=0;(s=h[C++])&&!(u=s.l(n,!1)););if(!u&&r)for(C=0;(s=h[C++])&&!(u=s.l(n,!0)););}if(s!=f.e||u!=f.n)f.e&&f.e.e(gr,n,f.n),f.e=s,f.n=u,s&&s.e(hr,
n,u);s?d==hr||d==gr?u=!1:(s.e(d,n,u),u=!0):u=!!x;u||(b.set("draggableCursor",c.get("draggableCursor")),e.set("title",null),delete n.Xa,Pm)})})}function TF(a,b,c){Pv;Pv;Pv;Pv;Pv}function UF(a,b){0!=Gt()lc||Ks(Is)||Qq()||rk[14]||Q(tf,function(a){a.b.b({ev:"api_watermark"})});var c=new yx(b,a[No],null),d=a.R();cp;cp;cp;cp}

Where "s" is null and therefore it cannot get the .lat or .lng properties.

I have tried setting the mouseover, mousemove and mouseout events to run "function(){}"  to test if it is related to these but this did not stop the error.

Please help.

Comment: I assume that's Google's compressed JS you've pasted in there? it's more likely you have an error in your JS somewhere in your page, and it would be of more benefit to see that in your question

Answer (score 0):

I know it's been a while, but I had the same problem and I was able to fix it by adding this at the end of the URL for the script tag:

```
&v=3.22
```

**EDIT:** I miscopied the fixing URL parameter